# How to pass Python MIME image in email body

Tags: python, html, email, mime

I'm sending email messages containing images in body like this:

```
    message = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
    message['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    message['From'] = email.utils.formataddr((SENDERNAME, SENDER))
    message['To'] = RECIPIENT

    relatedBody = MIMEMultipart("related")

    messageBody = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

    part1 = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')

    messageBody.attach(part1)
    messageBody.attach(part2)

    relatedBody.attach(messageBody)

    if logo_image:
        logo_img = MIMEImage(logo_image, logo_format)
        logo_img.add_header('Content-Id', '<logo_image>')  # angle brackets are important
        logo_img.add_header("Content-Disposition", "inline", filename="myimage")
        relatedBody.attach(logo_img)

    if hero_image:
        hero_img = MIMEImage(hero_image, hero_format)
        hero_img.add_header('Content-Id', '<hero_image>')  # angle brackets are important
        hero_img.add_header("Content-Disposition", "inline", filename="myimage")
        relatedBody.attach(hero_img)

    message.attach(relatedBody)
```

However, often they are observed as an attachment files in the letter - not as images in body.
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A couple points of clarification that I believe will meet your stated solution of attaching the image in the message body only.

1. Change the first line where you declare the message as "mixed" to "related". You only need "related" and "alternative" declarations.
2. Remove the part where you add the image as an "Content-Disposition". This is usually only done for attachments, so that alone may be your issue.
3. You need to actually open your image within your code to embed it to your email. See example below using the `with` statement (combined with the `open()` function) followed by the `read()` function.

New code for adding the images with your variable names:

```py
    message = MIMEMultipart("related")  # changed from "mixed" in question
    message['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    message['From'] = email.utils.formataddr((SENDERNAME, SENDER))
    message['To'] = RECIPIENT

    messageBody = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

    # Make sure BODY_HTML includes the tags:
    # <img src="cid:logo_image">
    # <img src="cid:hero_image">

    part1 = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')

    messageBody.attach(part1)
    messageBody.attach(part2)

    message.attach(messageBody)

    if logo_image:
        with open(logo_image, 'rb') as fp:
            message_img = MIMEImage(fp.read(), logo_format)
        message_img.add_header('Content-Id', '<logo_image>')  # angle brackets are important
        message.attach(message_img)

    if hero_image:
        with open(hero_image, 'rb') as fp:        
            message_img = MIMEImage(fp.read(), hero_format)
        message_img.add_header('Content-Id', '<hero_image>')
        message.attach(message_img)
```